# UI framework suggestion for Ember.js HTM5 => Phone Gap app (or alternative stack)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ember.js

**Background info:**
I'm a Rails developer, and I've been learning Ember.js over the summer. I have no experience developing mobile apps.

**Problem:**
Client is considering a native mobile app

**My proposed solution**
I'm looking at the possibility of doing an HTML5/CS/JS app using Ember.js, perhaps with some connection to a RAils API for data update; the app would be converted to native Android/iOS mobile apps using a tool such as PhoneGap, and hopefully some sort of UI framework such as Sencha touch, or Ionic, etc  that allows for a good UX.

**Question**
I'm looking for suggestions for a workable stack, a good UI framework that will work well with Ember.js, or an alternatives – perhaps I would be better off with Angular and ionic, etc.

I realize this is a somewhat vague question – I haven't been able to find for Ember.js any established solutions that hint at a viable direction such as angular/ionic. but I thought someone may know of some, or have put together a workable solution that could work.

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem and started developing a mobile iOS app using the Framework7 CSS. Since I wanted to have things like pull-to-refresh or opening the side panel by swiping - which is supported by Framework7 - I started digging into the code. I got everything working in Ember and created an Ember CLI addon out of it: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-framework7 . I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Here is a small demo of ember-cli-framework7: http://ember-mobile.github.dev/ember-cli-framework7/

Comment: Awesome –– I think this is meant to be .com instead of .dev

Comment: Yes, it is ... Its not the first time posting my [Pow](http://pow.cx/) URL :/ . Here the correct URL again: http://ember-mobile.github.io/ember-cli-framework7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution is using Cordova with the project https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova

If you would rather use phonegap, see http://givan.se/p/00000001 which writes up how to use an ember-cli project inside a phonegap project.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Gaurav! That looks promising! I'm guessing you created or have used this project –– any advice on a UI framework that will work well with Ember to produce a good mobile-friendly experience?

Comment: I haven't personally used any mobile UI framework other than JQuery Mobile and Foundation. However, in my admittedly limited experience once you understand Ember Views and Components, and the ember-cli build process, it is fairly straightforward to integrate any UX framework. So feel free to pick your favorite UX frameworks without worrying how well it works with Ember.js

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the advice! I wondered if I was missing out on anything that specifically addressed this type of project in the way that ionic and angular work puport to work together.